# wcf concurrent call raising timeout issue

Tags: wcf

I am having a wcf service which is hosted on iis, and I have given all timeout maximum value. When the service method was called at the same by 10 users through Silverlight application, it leads to timeout exception and no call back return to the application. This is not happening for all the time, but once it got failed all the subsequent calls raising the same issue. I have given single instance mode with per call context mode.

Comment: Check out this section **Instance mode = Per Session and Concurrency = Multiple** in this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and#Instance%20mode%20=%20per%20session%20and%20Concurrency%20=%20single

Comment: Thanks aravind, earlier it was per session with multiple, that doesn't solve my problem that's why now I am trying with per call with single mode.

Comment: post your code please